# iOS/android app for companion website - cross side scripting

Tags: android, ios, xss

I have a website, for which I've outsourced the dev of the companion iOS/Android app.

The dev of the app has asked me to enable cross site scripting for the app to work with the website.

Now, I know NOTHING about app development, but I know from the web point of view enabling XSS is a security risk.

So, is this request legit? Is there a way to limit it to the app or do some other security checking?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off developing an API and securing it with SSL and an API key. From a security perspective, an app isn't unlike a browser and as soon as XSS is enabled, anybody who figures out that it's there can impersonate your app.

Something like a JSON API will be more secure and is simple to implement on iOS and Android.